Requesting an object value from a website works manually but is undefined when executed with script
I am working on a script to retrieve the value of a class on a website (excel) so I can copy it/use it elsewhere in a script.
I am working in Apple Script but before I lose you I don't think you need to know any of that to help.
The function that this relates to is an apple script that has safari run a javascript. Here it is if that helps at all.
tell document 1 of application "Safari" --tells AS that we are going to use Safari
        
        set input to "document.getElementsByClassName('ewa-rteLine')[0].innerHTML;" -- uses JavaScript to set the variable input to the information we want
        
        do JavaScript input --tells the function to return the value of the variable input
    end tell
    
end getFormulaBarInput

To be clear, I am not trying to modify the object, just retrieve the value.
When I manually enter into the console on safari (because chrome doesn't play nice with AppleScript)
> document.getElementsByClassName('ewa-rteLine')[0].innerHTML;
< "2506077"

It returns the value of that class as expected.
But when I have the script enter it right after I get this error instead:
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementsByClassName('ewa-rteLine')[0].innerHTML')
    Global Code (Script Element 8:1)

I get this error, even though that class still has the same content and should therefore not be undefined?
Any help would be appreciated.

I do see that it could be related to the class name being given with single quotes in the script (eg: ('ewa-rteLine') and not ("ewa-rteLine")) however, in AppleScript I am limited as far as I have found because if I enter the code as:
set input to "document.getElementsByClassName("ewa-rteLine")[0].innerHTML;"
it expects the end of the line at ewa.
